# How to implement Brown-Out Reset, in STM32L496 MicroControler With STM32 Cube IDE Tool

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, hal, stm32cubeide, stm32ldiscovery

How to implement Brown-Out Reset by using STM32_HAL API's, what are the API's are required, Which pin  need to use for configuration, How check the input threshold value, How to Compare input threshold value and Brown-Out below modes.

```c
#define OB_BOR_LEVEL_0            ((uint32_t)FLASH_OPTR_BOR_LEV_0)     /*!< Reset level threshold is around 1.7V */
#define OB_BOR_LEVEL_1            ((uint32_t)FLASH_OPTR_BOR_LEV_1)     /*!< Reset level threshold is around 2.0V */
#define OB_BOR_LEVEL_2            ((uint32_t)FLASH_OPTR_BOR_LEV_2)     /*!< Reset level threshold is around 2.2V */
#define OB_BOR_LEVEL_3            ((uint32_t)FLASH_OPTR_BOR_LEV_3)     /*!< Reset level threshold is around 2.5V */
#define OB_BOR_LEVEL_4            ((uint32_t)FLASH_OPTR_BOR_LEV_4)     /*!< Reset level threshold is around 2.8V */
/**
```

I understood Brown-Out STM32 board, I refereed  below API's, But I am got some confusions on below API's, How to use and where to use.

```c
HAL_PWR_ConfigPVD(&hadc, PWR_PVDLEVEL_1);
HAL_PWR_EnablePVD();
HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
```

Comment: On "Description of STM32xx HAL and low-layer drivers" documentation of your MCU (search it and download it based on your MCU), for each section of the HAL APIs, there is a section of "How to use HAL drivers", read it.

Comment: Here is the link for [STM32L4 HAL and LL manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00173145-description-of-stm32l4l4-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf).